# what field should i choose to make it as primary key?

Tags: php

what should i do if i have a login form on a web page & it prompts me to enter an email as a username & password. if i design such web page should i take that email as a primary key? Because i'm not giving user a field  during user registration so that he/she can enter any integer ID that can be chosen as a primary key further. I also have other tables which belongs to this user & i need join to retrieve all the details. In this case how do i manage primary key. i can't take it auto generate because that needs to be entered in other tables also at the same time,which can't be possible with auto id.

Need help?

Comment: set an `auto incremental` field as `primary key` and make `username` and `email` fields as `unique`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should still use an `auto increment` to use as primary key. (and set a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the email address column).

When the user then logs in via your form, you should fetch the relevant row, and save that somewhere for the duration of the session (the time the user is logged in):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='johndoe@example.com' AND PASSWORD=SHA1('secret');
```

this then gives you the data you should use elsewhere in your application

**edit**

When you have 2 tables, 1 with the users and 1 with their profile, you have a **one-on-one** relation between those two. This means that one of the 2 tables should have a relation with the other, in the case of one-on-one, it is best to refer to the owning table from within the other one. since the user owns a profile this will come down to this:

```
user (id, email, password);
profile(id, user_id, contact, address);
```

To select both, you can then join them with the shared key:

```
SELECT * FROM user JOIN profile ON user.id = profile.user_id;
```

Although in this case it is even possible to reuse the user_id, as the `PRIMARY KEY` for the profile table. (this is inherently true for one-on-one relations, but may get you into trouble later if you choose to redesign your structure...)

To learn more about `FOREIGN KEYS`, refer to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Mind you, you do not **need** to specify the foreign key as a constraint, you can just create the column, and make sure programatically that the values are correct and consistent. But the constraint has multiple advantages:

- it will make sure there are no dangling rows (if configured correctly)
- it can take care of the deletion of child rows for you (`ON DELETE CASCADE`)
- you can not insert keys to non-existing references
- some ORMs can read the relationships straight from the schema

Comment: @ Nicky: i've these two tables:
user(auto_id,email,name,password);

profile(auto_id,contact,address,hometown,education);

in this case how do i make a join with the second table 'profile' where auto id's are not similer.

Comment: I'll add it in the post, it will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can set integer `id` as your primary key. And first you have to update user table then for the insert record you can get the `id` value and then you can insert in other table for others user related information. `Email` will be unique so you have to check email address exist or not before inserting any user. I think this will help you.

Comment: should i take id as auto incremented in every table to which i wanna make a join??

Comment: Yes make `id` as primary key in user table and other table as well. And in other table create `user_id` as foreign key where you will store the reference `id` from user table. And then later you can join and fetch the results.

Comment: suppose i do like this,

insert into user values('$id','$email','$username','$password');


but how will i get auto id from first table to enter it for second table?? should i write,

query= "select id from user where email='$email'";
mysql_query(query);

&
insert into user_profile values('$id','$user_id','$contact','$hometown','$address','$zip');

Comment: [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) will give you the last insert id. So just after the first query you can do `$user_id=mysql_insert_id();` and then the second query! Make sense.

Comment: yes! that's what i was looking for! thanks!
but here is one query also, will i still need to have auto_id in another tables as because auto_id will become useless in them cause i'm making foreign key which is primary key of first table will do the job.? so, should i still need?

Comment: Yes, you can set auto_id in the all table that's a good practice. Is there any issue with that. If above issue is solve then you can accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please use an auto-incremented integer column as primary key for your user table.
Use that ID as referencing the records. You can validate the email for its uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Only `id` should be a primary key and auto increment it. You should not give email as primary key. Before registration check whether the email id already exist. If exist restrict from registration and redirect else allow for registration.

Eg. registration table fields: id, name, email, password

User profile info fields: id, user_id, age, ....

Query

```
select * from reg_table a inner join profile_info b on a.id=b.user_id where a.id=1
```

Comment: okay! but if do not take email as primary key what is the another solution for this? How do i access other tables belongs to that user?

Comment: @kapil use id as a foreign key in other tables.

Comment: okay! but should i not take the  foreign-key column as auto incremented in other tables?

Comment: No foreign key column should not be auto incremented

Comment: okay, i'll make that join, like you described,but when i'll insert data into user table, shall i need to fetch auto_id from that table on behalf of email?
e.g., query="select auto_id from user where email='$email'";
or how will i get that id for fetching into another table?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an integer. Because this is your user reference you would have to update all your referencing tables when the mail-address is changed.

Comment: Yes! you are saying this true as because your given reason really matters!

Answer (score 0):

Disk space is no longer at the premium it once was, so, another thought, a tad controversial mind you is to use GUIDS as the primary key, getting more popular as they allow for the easy merging of databases.